# can I set ui-router state's data attribute dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, router

Imagine I have a state definition like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("main", {
   url: "main/:param/list",
   controller: "MainController",
   data: function($stateParams) {
      if($stateParams.param === "A") {
         return 'param1';
      } else if($stateParams.param === "B") {
         return 'param2';
      }
   }
}
```

Can I set data attribute like this? Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: do you think it is a valid question?? where you have defined **param1, param2**??

Comment: I am sorry I know what you mean, I will edit the question

Comment: why down vote?? is it duplicate? bad stated? why don't you comment below to help improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data object is a storage for any data you want to add to the $state service, which means you can store the function inside it, but you it won't be executed which i assume not what you're trying to achieve, You can learn about adding the custom data to the $state [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-custom-data)
, so to do the logic you wanna do you have to use the controller not the $state service, as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state("main", {
 url: "main/:param/list",
 controller: "MainController"/*,
 //only if you want to "store" your data on the $state, u can use it like this
 data: {
  myCustomParam: 'my Awesome Value'
 }*/
})//..all your other states

//now you pass the parameter in the url like This
//http://xxxxxxx/main/myparamvalue/list
//and in the controller
app.controller('MainController',function($state, $stateParams){
  //Here you do your Logic
  if($stateParams.param === "myparamvalue") {
     console.log('param1');//it should go here
  } else if($stateParams.param === "anythingelse") {
     console.log('param2');
  }
  /*if you have any values to get from the state data as previously mentioned you can get it like this*/
  console.log($state.current.data.myCustomParam);//output: my Awesome Value

});
```